# How to view a web page on an android app using WebView widget?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I have created this simple app that will view my webpage on a "webview" widget. It works with no interruptions and its is smooth when installing, but the thing is that it doesn't show the web page, instead it says "Web page not available".

Everything is good and no Errors in Eclipse, that is the code:

```
    private WebView myWebView;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.aramco-values.webs.com");
```

the SupportLint is initialized by Eclipse under the OnCreate method, I don't know if it is the problem or not because it must be there or  mtWebView  won't work.

ManiFest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aramcoapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.aramcoapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Eclipse warned me about the sdk that I have set at the beginning of the app creation

minimum = 11
target = 12

Comment: Q: Does your app specify "Internet permissions" in the Manifest .xml?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html might help you

Comment: @user3013091 Can you post the manifest file please?

Comment: Yes it specifies Internet permission in the ManiFest file.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the Internet and load web pages in a WebView, you must add the `INTERNET` permissions to your Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

**[EDIT]**

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         webView.loadUrl("http://www.aramco-values.webs.com");

         webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                        Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
                        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }
             });
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for the tip, but I have that already in my xml file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: please use the link for your source http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: @user3013091 I tried opening the URL on a test application and it worked fine for me. Please check my edited answer and let me know what the result is. Also, before you do anything, make sure your phone is connected to the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

you need to declare internet acess  permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

try now

Comment: Thank you Ydder, I've already said that my xml file is included with the permission to Mr .Joe. it still doesn't work.

Comment: update your page and you will see the ManiFest file in my question.

Comment: just for a hint, my device is Galaxy NOTE II running on Jelly Bean 4.1.2  with a wireless internet access.

Comment: Now it is working, but the problem is that it asks the user to switch to an actual internet browser.